# Ajax call returns some but not all Json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to have the user select some data, which is then inserted into a database using ajax. Then, I use ajax to get the new data from my json endpoint, so that I can update the webpage without reloading it. However, ajax call sometimes doesn't return all the updated data. For example, if the user were to select 3 items, the ajax call sometimes only returns the first 2 items.

Insert into database

```
$.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/api/addChampionForUser",
            data: params,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data.newChamp, function (key, val) {
                    if (val.mes) {
                        $(".message").append("<div> " + val.mes + " </div>");
                    }
                    else if (val.err) {
                        $(".message").append("<div> " + val.err + " </div>");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Get info from api

```
$.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/api/getChampions",
            data: params,
            //have also tried setting async to false
            async: true,
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data.champions, function(key, val){
                    $.each(val, function(k2, v2){
                        alert(v2.name + " " + v2.type);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
```

The json output looks like this:

```
{"champions":[[
      {
         "class":"championkeeper.Champion",
         "id":null,
         "name":"Aatrox",
         "type":"fighter",
         "user":"test"
      },
      {
         "class":"championkeeper.Champion",
         "id":null,
         "name":"Blitzcrank",
         "type":"fighter",
         "user":"test"
      },
      {
         "class":"championkeeper.Champion",
         "id":null,
         "name":"Darius",
         "type":"fighter",
         "user":"test"
      }
]]}
```

Comment: Given your json output hasn't been cut off and parses successfully, I would hazard a guess it's the API that's the culprit.

Comment: The API has the updated data when I refresh the page. But the first ajax call must not complete before the second one starts?

Comment: try adding `cache: false` to your ajax object.

Comment: I set both ajax calls to synchronous and it worked!

Comment: If you making your ajax synchronous fixes your issue, that means you confirmed that you encountered a "race" condition. Turning your XMLHttpRequest to synchronous mode is bad practice because it makes the javascript hang until the response comes back, and the feature is also deprecated for this exact reason. I don't see both AJAX requests in your code samples, but I would look at how you can "chain" your callbacks together so that you can keep your ajax requests async.

Comment: I have a javascript method that calls the first ajax call and another method that calls the second. Is there any way I can ensure the first ajax call has completed before the second one, without forcing it to be synchronous?